# Is it Possible To Query MySQL from VBA?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am not able to install the MySQL driver in my PC. In fact I can't install anything.
I was thinking of running the mysql.exe using the shell function in VBA as below:

```
RetVal = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\mysql.EXE", 1)
```

But how would I pass in a query and retrieve the query results? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's pretty easy. You'll have to use a ADO or ADODB Connection. You will be ablo to either execute a SQL Statement (ex. INSERT INTO x ...) or open a RecordSet to read SELECT statement.

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,100302

Make sure you have the proper references in your VBA references.

Good luck!

-Séb

Comment: first thing i said is that i CANT install any drivers. sigh-